# How to save a transformed XML document in itself

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

So I am loading an XML document, then I load XSLT code, I apply transformation on the loaded XML with the XSL and then I want to save the transformed XML on the place of the loaded one, basically replacing the object. 
This is how I am trying:

```
                Dim myXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
                Dim xsltTrans As New XslCompiledTransform()
                Dim tempMyXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
                'load the xml string taken from the database'
                myXmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlTilbudTilWord)
                'load the stylesheet'
                xsltTrans.Load(xsltTransformerCode.transformationXSLTcode())

                Dim xmlNavigator As XPathNavigator = myXmlDoc.CreateNavigator()
                Dim xmlWriter As XmlWriter = xmlNavigator.ReplaceRange(xmlNavigator)

                'HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO TRANSFORM THE 1st DOC TO THE TEMPORARY ONE'
                xsltTrans.Transform(myXmlDoc, Nothing, tempMyXmlDoc)
                myXmlDoc.Load(tempMyXmlDoc)
```

I have followed a tutorial from MSDN but it won't work and I don't really understand the thing with the Navigator -> Writer connection.

I am not using the `Transform()` method correctly, but I don't know how to make usage of the `writer` and the `navigator`, because I have to use them...

Answer (score 0):

Save will automatically overwrite the file if it already exists.

Comment: Forget the `.Save()`. My problem is somewhere within the `Navigator` and `XmlWriter` because, I suppose, I am not using them correctly. 
I just need to get the right order of using the methods from the API or smth like that. Apparently, I don't know it.